# Basic Antlr 3.1 Error Handling Issue (Python)

Tags: python, error-handling, antlr3

I created an Antlr 3.1 grammar I am using to parse an sql like language. The parsing is fine, but I am trying to make it spit out useful Exceptions. I have a set number of 'functions' that can be called with parenthesis, and then most other things are treated as resources. Currently if I try to parse
incorrectFunctionName(validStuff)
I get a recognition exception of

```
no viable alternative at input u'('
```

I would like to be able to say instead that incorrectFunctionName is not a valid function name, but am not sure how to get a hold of the last token, or where the best place is to put this handling code (Currently putting everything in displayRecognitionError).